# Limiting concurrence when processing a file line-by-line

Tags: node.js, async-await, request, fs, node-streams

I'm new to node.js, and trying to do the following:

- read csv file
- perform operation on the data in each line (handled by an API)
- write outcome to new file

I want to avoid loading the whole input file into memory, which is why I've used a stream. However, I'm running into the problem that I think I'm overloading my API because of sending too many requests at the same time. Is there a way to limit the amount of requests sent to the API?

Here is what I have come up with:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import csv from 'fast-csv';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

async function process_data(input){
    talk_options.body = JSON.stringify(input);
    let sendrequest = await fetch('api-url', talk_options)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {                
                let result = data.result;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                let result = {};
            });
    return result;
}

let readStream = fs.createReadStream('input.csv');
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('output.out');
let csvStream = csv.parse({headers: true});

csvStream.on('data', async function(data) {
    let processed_data = await process_data(data);
    writeStream.write(JSON.stringify(processed_data));
})
.on('end', function(){
    console.log('done');
})
.on('error', function(error){
    console.log(error);
});

let talk_options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': "application/json"},
    body: null
};

readStream.pipe(csvStream);
```

Thanks for any help or information in the right direction.

Comment: you will want some sort of `flush` logic otherwise you will send an API request for every line of the CSV. so, fill an array of processed_data, then write a bulk request to your API

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that maybe there was something built-in or another package where it would be easy to set some kind of limit to either the stream, or to how many requests are sent to the API simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **rate limit** the code that processes the data. I mean, you likely have to do it anyway, since you are calling an API.

I highly recommend [reservoir intervals with bottleneck](https://github.com/SGrondin/bottleneck#reservoir-intervals).